# WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information

Tags: testng

I was trying to execute below code, but it throws error since last two days. Earlier it was working, but now it isn't.

Using framework (Selenium webdriver, Java, TestNG)

Code:

---

```
package Test;

import java.io.File;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;


public class TestNG_Login {
    public WebDriver driver;

  @Test

  public void main() {

    //create web Object
        WebElement email;
        WebElement password;
        WebElement login;
        email = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
        email.sendKeys("mmanes44@gmail.com");
        password = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
        password.sendKeys("vms2014");
        login = driver.findElement(By.className("icon-arrow-right"));               
        login.click();
  }

  @BeforeMethod

  public void beforeMethod() {

      //Open the URL in Chrome
        File file = new File("D:\\chromedriver_win32_2.3\\chromedriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://54.86.179.54:8080/VMS/user/login.htm#login");
        driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
}

  @AfterMethod

  public void afterMethod() {
    //Close the browser
      driver.quit();
  }

}
```

---

I got the same error for Firefox and could not run the script. It open the browser for a while nothing happen and close the browser.

Please advice.

Thanks in Advance,

Mahesh

Comment: For FireFox below error displayed...org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follows: *** Blocklist::_preloadBlocklistFile: blocklist is disabled
1427217675513 addons.manager DEBUG Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>

Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: 
System info: host: 'Mahesh', ip: , os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: , os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_31'

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got the reason for the above mentioned error.

Firefox automatically updated to latest version and this Selenium browser driver could not recognise the instance of the driver and therefore thrown error.

Solution:

Uninstall the latest browser version and install the Firefox v29 or supported by Selenium Webdriver and now run the script.

Script will run successfully.

Make sure "Firefox update" to Auto should be uncheck all the time. (Go to Option > Advanced > update tab)

Best Regards,
Mahesh Mane